# trigger lambda from SQS event on different VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have my SQS URL which is configured in one VPC and want to trigger Lambda function from another VPC based on any new message that comes in SQS. How can i achieve it for real time analysis.

Comment: What have you tried and what difficulty are you currently facing?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS is not associated with Amazon VPC. It exists "outside" of VPCs.

Therefore, you can simply configure the Lambda function to use the SQS queue as a trigger.

Comment: my sqs is in different aws account and lmbda is in different aws account. How can i set trigger

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this information, and anything else that might be relevant.